# Change translation format in Craft CMS

Tags: craft3, localization

I'm trying to get my Craft translations to work with the translation management tool [Phraseapp](https://phraseapp.com).

The standard format for translation-files in Craft CMS looks like this:

```
# de.php

return [ 
    'good_morning' => 'Guten morgen', 
    'KEY' => 'GERMAN_TRANSLATION_VALUE'
];
```

But this format is not supported by Phraseapp.

Is there a way to return **json** or **yaml** instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to use PhraseApp to manage Craft translations, but as of Craft 3, we don't anymore (everything is now on [Github](https://github.com/craftcms/cms)).

When we were using them, we wrote a quick PHP script that would take the PHP based translation file format Craft uses, parse them and convert them to a format that PhraseApp could use.  Then there was another quick script that would reverse the process when we pulled them down.